# get all posts from a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm trying to get all posts from a particular custom post type using the following code:

```
$auctions = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'auction'));
print_r($auctions);
echo '<select>';
foreach ($auctions as $auction) {
    echo '<option value="' . $auction->ID . '">' . $auction->post_title . '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Although the print_r() call shows data, the foreach seems to ignore it and doesn't print anything. Any ideas?

Any help would be appreciated

print_r() output:

```
Array (
    [0] => WP_Post Object (
        [ID] => 36
        [post_author] => 1
        [post_date] =>    2013-05-19 10:58:45
        [post_date_gmt] => 2013-05-19 08:58:45
        [post_content] =>
        [post_title] => My Title
        [post_excerpt] =>
        [post_status] => publish
        [comment_status] => closed
        [ping_status] => closed
        [post_password] =>
        [post_name] => my-title
        [to_ping] =>
        [pinged] =>
        [post_modified] => 2013-05-24 09:55:53
        [post_modified_gmt] => 2013-05-24 07:55:53
        [post_content_filtered] =>
        [post_parent] => 0
        [guid] => http://domain.com/?post_type=auction&p=36
        [menu_order] => 0
        [post_type] => auction
        [post_mime_type] =>
        [comment_count] => 0
        [filter] => raw
    )   
)
```

Comment: What does the `print_r( $auctions );` output? (Add it to your question; it'll be very hard to read in the comments.)

Comment: print_r() data added

Comment: Does the `<select>...</select>` statement show up in the generated HTML?  If you view the source of your page, does it look correct?

Comment: Oops... a typo I made prevented the correct output. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @user1991185 is that typo had been the issue and question is resolved?

Answer (score 13):

You can use `wp_query()` for this to work

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'auction',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );
$query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($query->have_posts()): 
    echo '<select>';
    while ($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post();
            echo '<option value="' . get_the_ID() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</option>';
    endwhile;
    echo '</select>';
    wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
```

Documentation for `WP_Query` https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: please update the code with `wp_reset_postdata()`. There is a mistake.

Comment: Got an error because there is a semicolon missing in line 4 (after the $args array). 
Might want to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps because `get_posts` returns an object, you need to setup post data per [Codex get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts). Replacing line 4:

```
foreach($auctions as $auction) : setup_postdata($auction) {
```

Comment: get_posts() returns an array http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Return_Value, running setup_postdata would be used to allow the use template tags, like the_ID()

Comment: Ah, yes, I see that further down the page. Thanks @AndrewBartel

Comment: Note that such loops are typically `as $post` to set global `$post` or it needs to be done additionally. `setup_postdata()` doesn't do this.

Comment: Great catch @Rarst.. good to know that one.

Answer (score 1):

Try it without get_posts(). I currently have a similar function that works like this:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'customPostName', 'post_status' => 'publish');
$pages = get_pages($args);
foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
    // Do something
    }
```

Edit: Actually I'm not sure why this isn't working since codex clearly says to use `echo $post->ID;` with get_posts. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts#Access_all_post_data

Does this make any difference for you?

```
    foreach ($auctions as $auction) {
        $option = '<option value="';
        $option .= $auction->ID;
        $option .= '">';
        $option .= $auction->post_title;
        $option .= '</option>';

        echo $option;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        'post_type' => 'auction',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    );
$query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($query->have_posts() ) : 
    echo '<select>';
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
            echo '<option value="' . get_the_ID() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</option>';
    endwhile;
    echo '</select>';
    wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
```

@gregory was actually right, but had a few typos... There was a closing `;` missing from the array and at the end `reset_postdata();` has to become `wp_reset_postdata();`.
This should work just fine now... It works great for me, without any problem!
Hope this will help!